# NSDateFormatter has different results when iPad has a 24-hour format

Tags: ipad, ios, nsdateformatter

I've been pondering on why this happens for a while now, and I've got no clue. If you run the following code:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy|HH:mm"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"18-01-2011|06:00"];
NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] init];

NSLog(@"date is: %@, today is %@", date, today);
```

If the user has configured a 24-hour clock the above prints `date is: 2011-01-18 11:00:00 +0000, today is 2011-01-19 00:56:56 +0000`. However, when the user selects a 12-hour clock, the above prints `date is: (null), today is 2011-01-19 12:58:51 a.m. +0000`.

What I'm I doing wrong? Isn't `formatter` suppososed to be independent of the locale? please help!

Comment: [Apple QA1480](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1480.html) explains an issue with NSDateFormatter and the 24-Hour Time setting which may apply in your case.

Comment: Thanks aBitObvius, finally I understand how it works! post it as an answer so I can upvote it :)

Comment: How do I put 06h00 instead of 06:00?

Comment: You may want to look at http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns