# NSDateFormatter stringFromDate works in simulator not on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, nsdateformatter

I have a universal app, targeting both `iPhone` and `iPad` and only supporting `iOS 6+`

I have a very simple piece of code to pull the time from an `NSDate` and format it for display:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
validFromField.text = [formatter stringFromDate:fromDate];
```

With a date of `'01/01/2012 10:00'` in fromDate, on the iPhone Simulator, iPad Simulator and real iPhone 4S I get the expected value of `'10:00 AM'`

However, on my iPad (3, new iPad) I get `'10:00'` as though the `'a'` in the formatter is being ignored.

Both the iPhone and iPad are running `iOS 6.0.1`

Has anyone encountered this problem, or know how to fix it?

Comment: This is because the date format of system and iPad may not be the same.. NSLog [NSDate date] and run in both and check the format..

Comment: I'm not allowed to answer my own question yet, but the answer to my question was found in another SO question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730779/nsdateformatter-has-different-results-when-ipad-has-a-24-hour-format?rq=1

And in particular backed up by the Apple Technical Q&A here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html

Comment: @Anusha, You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @ACB But he got answer from some other links..

Comment: Ya, I saw that. I felt basically the issue was with that difference in date format set in iPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question in another SO question here: [NSDateFormatter has different results when iPad has a 24-hour format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730779/)…

Backed up by the Apple Technical Q&A here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html

So in essence if the device is set to 24 hour time then the `'a'` flag in the formatter is ignored and the time will be returned in 24 hour format.