# stringFromDate crash on special device

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I use NSDateFormatter to convert the timeStamp to string 
this my code

> ```
> let string = NSString(string: timeStamp)
>
> let timeSta:NSTimeInterval = string.doubleValue
>
> print("timeStamp:\(timeStamp) with double value \(timeSta)")
>
> let dfmatter = NSDateFormatter()
> dfmatter.dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
> dfmatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "zh_CN")
> let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timeSta)
> print(dfmatter.stringFromDate(date))
> return dfmatter.stringFromDate(date)
> ```

When I run this code in my iPad it's crash in

> stringFromDate

,but I run it in iPhone it's works fine

I have try to set the system time with 12 hours it' crash too.

Comment: what's your timeStamp value?

Comment: timeStamp:1553759751.415 with double value 1553759751.415 @kb920

Comment: it's returning 2019-03-28. I have 12 hours format in my simulator

Comment: only crash in my iPad , I have try in 4 kind of iPhone it's work fine @kb920

Comment: check region in iPad.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107591/discussion-between-kb920-and-jansma).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question in another SO question here: [NSDateFormatter has different results when iPad has a 24-hour format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730779/nsdateformatter-has-different-results-when-ipad-has-a-24-hour-format)

Backed up by the Apple Technical Q&A here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html

So in essence if the device is set to 24 hour time then the 'a' flag in the formatter is ignored and the time will be returned in 24 hour format.